# Baking Normal Maps to new UV map - How to avoid pixellation and stepping

Tags: texture-baking

I'm trying to bake a Normal map texture from one UV map to another but keep getting extremely poor results including stepping and pixellation. [image]

The mesh is identical and even in areas where the UVs haven't changed I'm getting major issues. I've tried everything alnd lookg for any help in improvig the results.

Answer (score 2):

Solved!: The original Normal map was a 32bit Tiff which Blender is unable to save as. Saving as a 32bit Float EXR solved the issues.